# Sending Old Data back to Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up this Vue component so that if there is an error in my backend validation from Laravel then I can save the inputs and when it redirects back to the create page then auto-populate with the old data.

As of right now it's not sending the old data to the prop for my component. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Blade File

```
<component name="{{ old('name') }}" locationType="{{ old('location_type') }}" paymentType="{{ old('payment_type') }}"></component>
```

Vue Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p class="mbxs"><b>Choose Location Type <span style="color: red">*</span></b></p>
      <label class="custom-control custom-radio" v-for="choice in choices">
        <input name="location_type" type="radio" v-model="chosen" :value="choice" class="custom-control-input" required>
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">{{ choice }}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <template v-if=" chosen == 'Residential' ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group form-group-required">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" required name="last_name" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group form-group-required">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" required name="first_name" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-if=" chosen == 'Commercial' ">
      <div class="form-group form-group-required">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" required name="name" type="text">
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
  http: {
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken
    }
  },
  props: [ 'name', 'locationType', 'paymentType' ],
  data: function(){
    return {
      name: '',
      locationType: '',
      locationName: '',
      paymentType: '',
      insuranceType: '',
      choices: [ 'Commercial', 'Residential'],
      chosen: ''
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why is there 'redirects' involved?   Are you not posting the form data through ajax?   If you use axios to post your form to Laravel validate it and return the errors if there are any you can then catch those errors and render them under your inputs without worrying about a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're defining the props `this.name, this.locationType, this.PaymentType`, then you're assigning them as empty in your `data` declaration, so you have a collision.

Given your architecture, its not the most elegant, but it will probably do:

```
props: [ 'name', 'locationType', 'paymentType' ],
created: function() {
    this.form.name = this.name;
    this.form.locationType = this.locationType;
    this.form.paymentType = this.paymentType;        
},
data: function() {
    form: {
        name: '',
        locationType: '',
        locationName: '',
        paymentType: '',
        insuranceType: '',
        choices: [ 'Commercial', 'Residential'],
        chosen: ''
    }
}
```

We've namespaced our data to `form` and assign the values from our properties to the `form` namespace.

Update your bindings as such to `v-model="form.name"` etc.